# SVG XML background in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I'm trying to get the following code parsed into React Native as a background image:

```
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' 
height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cg fill='%23ffb6c1' fill-opacity='0.16'%3E%3Cpolygon fill- 
rule='evenodd' points='8 4 12 6 8 8 6 12 4 8 0 6 4 4 6 0 8 4'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

Using URL decoding, I get the XML as follows:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
  <g 
    fill='#ffb6c1' 
    fill-opacity='0.2'>
  <polygon 
    fill-rule='evenodd' 
    points='8 4 12 6 8 8 6 12 4 8 0 6 4 4 6 0 8 4'/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I tried using the following package: https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg to create an SVG XML component like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { SvgUri, SvgXml } from "react-native-svg";

const xml = `
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
  <g
    fill='#ffb6c1'
    fill-opacity='0.2'
  >
    <
      polygon fill-rule='evenodd'
      points='8 4 12 6 8 8 6 12 4 8 0 6 4 4 6 0 8 4'
    />
  </g>
</svg>
`;

export default () => <SvgXml xml={xml} width="100%" height="100%" />;
```

However I get the following error:
[image]

Appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: remove the whitespace between < and polygon

Comment: Thanks, it now renders a single svg image. Just need to figure out how to repeat it and use it as a background pattern. I'll open another ticket.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment above, turns out it was just a white space issue on the polygon opening tag.

Correct react code:

```
import React from "react";
import { SvgUri, SvgXml } from "react-native-svg";

const xml = `
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 
24'>
  <g
    fill='#ffb6c1'
    fill-opacity='0.2'
  >
    <polygon 
       fill-rule='evenodd'
       points='8 4 12 6 8 8 6 12 4 8 0 6 4 4 6 0 8 4'
  />
  </g>
</svg>
`;

export default () => <SvgXml xml={xml} width="100%" height="100%" />;
```